# Getting Geographic Information Systems GIS of a Street / Road in any Maps Api

Tags: iphone, google-maps, openstreetmap, bing-maps

I am trying to Get Entire Road Data in my application. Let's say I have a road named as Abc Street or Xyz road, I want to get atleast its starting geo point and final/ending geo point so that i can draw a polyline over the entire road.

I am wondering if there are any api features in Any map apis out there. Google/Apple/OpenStreet/Bing etc

OpenStreet maps allow you to download "ways" entire file. however downloading and appending a GB file inside my app will be no good. Any easier way would be appreciated

I have tried using this query

```
<osm-script output="json">
  <query type="way">
    <has-kv k="highway" regv="Nimitz Freeway"/>
  </query>
  <print/>
</osm-script>
```

Nimitz Freeway is a quite popular Highway in oakland USA however using

[OverPassTurbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/?Q=%3Cquery%20type%3D%22node%22%3E%0A%20%20%3Caround%20%7B%7Bcenter%7D%7D%20radius%3D%22100.0%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%3Chas-kv%20k%3D%22amenity%22%20v%3D%22cafe%22%20%2F%3E%0A%3C%2Fquery%3E%0A%3Cprint%20%2F%3E)

The results are unsuccessful. Perhaps if anyone can help me do a little more understanding of this api

Comment: Maybe you explain also what you want to do with that data. As pointed out there is the Overpass API for parts but if you want to develop a routing solution there are some of them like GraphHopper (for devices like Android or iOS) which can do this offline and more efficient

Comment: @Karussell i just want to get geo points of entire road and display on map as polyline in iPhone. I am looking at overpass api already , it sounds promising, trying it, let's see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of OpenStreetMap you can download individual roads using the [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API). In your case a [query for name and rough location](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide#By_exact_name_and_rough_location) seems to fit. The correct [tag](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tags) for roads is the [highway tag](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:highway).